# Django model save()'s resistance to SIGTERM

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a celery task which generates some data and saves them to the database using the Django's `save()` method. Sometimes I need to stop it which is done by sending a `SIGTERM` to it.

I wonder, might it happen that I will be unlucky enough to send that signal in the middle of saving, ending up with some mess in the database and/or Django models?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2700), `SIGTERM` does not do a warm shutdown and you are likely to have some mess.

Instead, you should use `SIGINT` which will wait for the task to finish and then it will close.

[This thread](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2700) may be helpful as well.

**UPDATE:**

`SIGTERM` is *the termination signal*. Its intention is to kill the process, gracefully or not.

`SIGINT` is *the interrupt signal*. Its intention is to provide a mechanism for an orderly, graceful shutdown.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You say that `SIGINT` will wait for the task to finish. Isn't it what the task would do naturally? What is actually the purpose of `SIGINT` here?

Comment: I think we miss each other a little bit. I want to kill only a celery task that is being executed, not the whole celery. That is why I am missing the purpose of `SIGINT` when it actually *waits* for the task to finish.